# Add new Widget when button is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a button add a new widget when it's clicked.

To make it simple , I'm having this widget :

```
Column(
                              children: [
                                InputField(
                                  label: "Product",
                                  content: "Type product Name",
                                  fieldValidator: (value) {
                                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                      return "This input is required";
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                ),
```

As you can see , I want a button that adds a new `InputField` inside this column.
And if it's possible how can I make the button only appear at the end of the last item .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a list to control InputField data.

```
final List<String> inputs = [];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  retrun Column(
          children: [
            ...inputs.map((input) => InputField(...))toList(),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('click'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  inputs.add('');
                });
              }
            ),
          ],
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable to hold a list of `InputField` and display them dynamically using :

```
Column(
    children: inputs.map((dynamic e) {
        return e;
    }).toList(),
)
```

And then you can wrap in with a `Column` or `ListView` to display the button:

```
Column(
    children:[
        Column(
            children: inputs.map((dynamic e) {
                return e;
        }).toList(),
        _Button()
)
    ]
)
```

Of course it is not the "best" solution, implementation depends on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Best use the listview builder to build the dynamic text view widgets

```
Map<TextEditingController, int> list = Map();

ListView.builder(
   itemCount: list.lenght,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
   return TextFormField()
  }
)
```

Inside the list add `TextEditingController` so that you can get value from the textformfield.

or you can use the key for each widget to get the value from the widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
Column(children: [
  Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widgets.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return widgets[index];
      },
    ),
  ),
  TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          widgets.add(const Text("New Widget"));
        });
      },
      child: const Text("add Widget"))
]);
```